# Capturing checkbox selection event in prime dataTable

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

In the prime datatable I have a checkbox to select multiple rows. When I select or unselect the checkbox, all the rows get selected/unselected correctly. On selecting or unselecting the checkbox I want to disable few buttons at the top. Hence I need help in knowing the attribute to capture selection.

```
<p-dataTable> 
    <p-column selectionMode="multiple">
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: and why did you tag it PrimeFaces? Please click the tag, read the text, did you use that?

Answer (score 0):

use onRowSelect and onRowUnselect events
for example :
(onRowSelect)="updateSelected($event)" (onRowUnselect)="updateSelected($event)"

Answer (score -1):

`onHeaderCheckboxToggle` did the trick.

Comment: Where did you place that? A little more explanation and code would be appreciated